# Passing data to WCF with every call

Tags: wcf, appdomain

How could a string be passed with every call of a WCF service (without singleton). For instance, I need the CultureInfo string to be passed with every call.
Earlier in Remoting I useed to pass the data from client like

```
CallContext.LogicalSetData("CultureInfo", "en-Us")
```

and retrieve in server (running in different appdomain) like

```
CallContext.LogicalGetData("CultureInfo").
```

This is not working in WCF. Always the CallContext.LogicalGetData is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately in WCF, it isn't quite as easy.  However, you can do it once for all operations.  You can implement [IClientMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx) which allows you to modify every request before sending it.  Then add your custom message header.  Note that this is a Soap Message Header not an HTTP header.

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,
    System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
    request.Headers.Add(MessageHeader.CreateHeader("CultureInfo",
        "http://mynamespace", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name));
    return null;
}
```

On the server side, implement [IDispatchMessageInspector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request,
    IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    string culture = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("CultureInfo",
        "http://mynamespace");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
        = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
    return null;
}
```

You'll also need to implement some custom behaviors to apply the message inspectors.  For implementing the behaviors, see the MSDN pages:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.iclientmessageinspector.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: thanks Robert. I implemented it using your above sample both as endpointbehvior (adding to serives end point) as well as customattribute (decorating the interface contract with customattribute ).Both works fine independently. Is there any advantage of using one over the other.

Comment: Glad it worked.  I think the advantage of the endpoint behavior is that it can be added via configuration.  The attribute implementation requires a recompile.  If you're ever in a situation in which the behavior needs to be added to the client after it is deployed, the behavior could be preferable.  On the other hand, the attribute is clearer to someone else reading the code later.